# Designated Initializers, waste unused and unnecessary memory? how to allocate only the needed part of the array?

Tags: c

I want to use designated initializers, but what about the others index that aren't initialized?

Are they spend my memory too?

for example:

EDIT PART: {

int array[590] = {[2] = 1};

note: I don't use the other array index, like this example i want to use only one, but i  will allocate memory for another index?

(okey I know that this example is vague, i don't want only one int or any other type, I  don't know how to explain what I want. But I think that explain it is not necessary because my question is not 'how to accomplish this' my question is 'whats happen when I do it?' or 'how it is implemented?', thanks a lot.)

what about the memory in this?
 I waste 590 piece of memory, or only one?
 If the first is correct, how Can I spend only one?

and if I do this:?

int array [] = { [2] = 1, [590] = 2};

I will allocate 590 piece of memory, or only two?

}

Thanks so much!

Comment: waste = allocate memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's ask Mr. Compiler!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int array[] = {[2] = 1, [590] = 2};
    printf("sizeof(array) is %d bytes\n", sizeof(array));
}
```

Survey says:

```
$ gcc initsize.c
$ ./a.out
sizeof(array) is 2364 bytes
```

Yep! 591 * 4 = 2364.

Here, you've allocated a 591 element integer array on the stack. It *has* to be allocated; the compiler does not know what you may do with it (pass it to a library function it knows nothing about, for example). You told it the size is 591 elements, and it obeys...

P.S. There are *many* "sparse matrix" C libraries; just google for "C library sparse matrix". But, for a vector of 591 elements, they are total over-kill. Now, if you have 10,000 of such vectors, that's another story.

Comment: So, how to accomplish what I want? allocate only parts of my index?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the declaration you use will create an array of 5 elements, and only set one of them to the value '1'. The rest will be uninitialised (I believe).

What you want, I think, is a hash table or some other kind of associative container, which C does not have in it's standard library. You'll either have to write one yourself, or find one that someone else has written.

Comment: You need to implement an associated container. There is no such thing in the standard C library, but it's not *that* hard to implement yourself. Of course, for such a small array as the one in your example, it really doesn't matter but I assume you're planning on much bigger arrays. Kevin Little gave you some good keywords to plug into google...

Comment: The rest will *not* be uninitialised - they will be implicitly initialised to 0.  Objects in C are *never* partially initialised, so if you have an initialiser for one member of an array, the entire array is initialised.

Comment: @caf: I stand corrected. I did a quick google to check before I posted my answer, but I got conflicting answers so I just went with the safest assumption :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes memory is allocated when you declare an array, even though you dont initialize every element. If you want only one value stored you need a single variable, you can also Allocate memory dinamically but it requires a good knolewdge of pointers and memory allocation/management functions (malloc,realloc,free,etc.)

Comment: So, how I can allocate dinamically to avoid spend my memory?

Comment: MALLOC:
Allocates memory requests size of bytes and returns a pointer to the Ist byte of allocated space.

CALLOC:
Allocates space for an array of elements initializes them to zero and returns a pointer to the memory

FREE:
Frees previously allocated space

REALLOC:
Modifies the size of previously allocated space.

Comment: The link is for a dynamic memory allocation tutorial.
http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c.html